# How can I select an item from a select list after populating it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following HTML:

```
<span>SubTopic {{ modal.option.sSubTopic }}</span>
<select data-ng-model="modal.option.sSubTopic"
   data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in modal.option.subTopics">
</select>
```

In my controller

```
 $http.get(url, { cache: us.oneDayCache })
    .success(function (data) {
       $scope.modal.option.subTopics = data;
       $scope.modal.option.sSubTopic = "2";
    })
```

After the get the {{ }} value is set to 2 but the 2nd item of my select is not selected.

Is there something wrong with the way I am doing this?

Comment: Check the type of item.id as I believe angular uses === for comparing model property and selected item key.

Comment: Can you post what your data object looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying the value of the field to be the `id` of the item with `item.id as` in the `ngOptions`. The model value needs to match the value of the `data` `id` you want selected.  If you want the second object, it would be `data[1].id`

```
$http.get(url, { cache: us.oneDayCache })
    .success(function (data) {
       $scope.modal.option.subTopics = data;
       $scope.modal.option.sSubTopic = data[1].id;
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/gteX9/2/

Comment: I'm sorry I should have changed this. I actually tried both with and without the quotes. Neither are working for me.

Comment: Thanks - I tried your demo. Wish my code was working. I will still keep trying. Seems a very simple thing. Could there be a scope problem do you think ?

Comment: I added a new demo with real AJAX (it was a pain, jsfiddle wants the payload a certain way in order to return it), using the number vs string still works.  Perhaps when you previously tried a numeric, the string version was still cached.

Comment: I will keep trying and update the answer. You might be right about the cache.

Comment: So, I was wrong, I updated my answer to be correct.  Previously it just so happened to work because the second option had an `id` of `2`, and I was passing `2`.  Now it will work for any `id` of the second option.

Comment: Thanks. I will check again soon. Glad to see your revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

The data-ng-model contains the model in which the selected value will be stored. In your case this would mean you'd store the selected value in 2. That doesn't seem right. Perhaps you could try something like:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in modal.options.subTopics"></select>
<pre>{{selectedItem}}</pre>
```

$scope.selectedItem contains your selected item. Now you want to select the second item in your data object. You could do that by doing this in your controller:

```
$http.get(url, { cache: us.oneDayCache })
.success(function (data) {
    $scope.modal.option.subTopics = data;
    $scope.selectedItem = data[1];
})
```

Wasn't able to test it here, but it should work.